# it gives an alert on eclipse : Unable to Update : appengine-api-1.0-sdk-1.5.0.jar (Access is denied) when deployed to GAE

Tags: google-app-engine

I am unable to deploy my application to google app engine however I can deploy it when I try 2nd or 3rd time. I get an alert on eclise as well as the log on console as below:

------------ Deploying frontend ------------

Preparing to deploy:
    Created staging directory at: 'C:\DOCUME~1\bg92344\LOCALS~1\Temp\appcfg2387862893654282649.tmp'
    Scanning for jsp files.
    Compiling jsp files.
    Scanning files on local disk.
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\DOCUME~1\bg92344\LOCALS~1\Temp\appcfg2387862893654282649.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\appengine-api-1.0-sdk-1.5.0.jar (Access is denied)

Debugging information may be found in C:\Documents and Settings\bg92344\Local Settings\Temp\appengine-deploy8040646126412995823.log

One thing that I found peculiar that when I go to Temp\appcfg2387862893654282649.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\ the jar appengine-api-1.0-sdk-1.5.0.jar dissapears after i get this alert, I guess it is not copying the jar completely. I dont know why :( 
Can anybody help me out on this. Thanks in advance.

Regards,
BaleSabu

Comment: What version of Eclipe are you using? What version of the Google Plugin for Eclipse (GPE)?

Answer (score 0):

1 Login from Eclipse to your Google account (left bottom icon)

2 Check you application id before deploy. Should be same to your application.

3 Your user should have owner or admin role for application you want to deploy

Answer (score 0):

Try cleaning and rebuilding your project before attempting to deploy again. Alternatively try to restart your IDE or computer. This fixed my errors in Android Studio.